# How to get the count of unread messages in React native with gifted chat library?

Tags: react-native, google-cloud-firestore, react-native-gifted-chat

Am currently using react native gifted chat for the message/chat feature in my application.
Now I want to show the unread messages for the user, does anyone have an idea about it or any suggestions to tackle this.
Any help/Suggestion will be appreciated,
Thanks in advance.

[React native gifted chat link](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-gifted-chat)

Answer (score 0):

There is no such feature right now. But you can do that on chat list screen by managing the messages.
After you receive a message you can mark as delivered and store and when you open mark as read. So you can count no. of messages with unread status. you have to manage it using redux.